# Splitting a comma delimited string in chunks of 40

Tags: javascript

So I have a string which looks like this:

123,532,0302,1234,etc etc (and it goes on and on, sometimes over 500). However, I want to split the comma dilimted list into arrays of 40, nothing more. Similar to [array_chunk](http://nl.php.net/manual/function.array-chunk.php) in PHP (but with arrays).

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: It is not clear to me whether you want the results to be multiple 40 item arrays or multiple strings where each string has 40 comma delimited items in it.  My answer below offers both possibilities because I wasn't sure from your question which type of result you wanted.

Answer (score 4):

```
String.prototype.chunk = function(n) {
if (typeof n=='undefined') n=2;
return this.match(RegExp('.{1,'+n+'}','g'));
};
```

Sample usage:

```
var s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234';
var a = s.chunk(6);
```

yields:

```
var a = ['abcdef','ghijkl','mnopqr','stuvwx','yz1234'];
```

taken from http://javascript.about.com/library/blchunk.htm

**EDIT: I realize my first answer did not answer the question so please look here:**

```
String.prototype.chunkArr = function (length) {
    var data = this.split(",");
    var result = Array();
    while(data.length > 0) {
        result.push(
            data.splice(0,length)
            .join(",") // comment this or remove line out if you don't want it to re-join into a CSV list of 40 items
        );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
myData = "1,2,3,2,4,5,1,5,1,23,1,23,12,3,12,3,12,3,12,3,12,3,12";
console.log(myData.chunkArr(2)); // Change 2 to 40 if you have longer data
```

yields:

```
myData = ["1,2", "3,2", "4,5", "1,5", "1,23", "1,23", "12,3", "12,3", "12,3", "12,3", "12,3", "12"]
```

if you comment out or remove the `.join(",")` section (around line 7) in the above `chunkArr` function, the function yields:

```
myData = [
    ["1", "2"], 
    ["3", "2"], 
    ["4", "5"], 
    ["1", "5"], 
    ["1", "23"], 
    ["1", "23"], 
    //... and so on
]
```

Yes, i'm aware i could've just added a second argument to change the 'mode'.. but laziness ensued :)

Comment: I see, only problem with that is, I don't want it to chunk by characters, I want it to grab a load of 40 items on the list and split them.

Comment: Ah alright, I edited my answer to answer your question.. which is also much simpler using `splice` instead of another inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the desired output correctly, you can split on all the commas and then break the resulting long array into several arrays of no more than 40.

```
function splitChunkIntoArrays(data, chunkLength) {
    var temp = data.split(",");
    var output = [];
    var item = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        // if item is now full, put it into the result and start a new chunk
        if (item.length == chunkLength) {
            output.push(item);
            item = [];
        }
        item.push(temp[i]);
    }
    // if anything in the last chunk, put it in the result
    if (item.length != 0) {
        output.push(item);
    }
    return(output);
}

// sample output from splitChunkIntoArrays:
[
    [1,2,3,4,..40],
    [41,42,43,...80],
    [81,82,83,...120],
    [121,123,124]
]
```

This will give you an array of arrays where each inner array is no longer than chunkLength items long.

If you wanted the resulting 40 item long pieces to still be strings (something that wasn't entirely clear in your question), you could then join the inner arrays again:

```
function splitChunkIntoStrings(data, chunkLength) {
    var splitData = splitChunkIntoArrays(data, chunkLength);
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < splitData.length i++) {
        results.push(splitData[i].join(","));
    }
    return(results);
}

// sample output from splitChunkIntoStrings:
[
    "1,2,3,4,..40",
    "41,42,43,...80",
    "81,82,83,...120",
    "121,123,124"
]
```

This would result an array of strings, where each string has 40 or less comma separated values.

---

And, here's a bit more streamline version of the first function using array `splice()`:

```
function splitChunkIntoArrays(data, chunkLength) {
    var temp = data.split(","), result = [];
    while (temp.length > 0) {
        result.push(temp.splice(0, chunkLength));
    }
    return(result);
}
```

or if you want the results to still be strings, you can do this:

```
function splitChunkIntoStrings(data, chunkLength) {
    var temp = data.split(","), result = [];
    while (temp.length > 0) {
        result.push(temp.splice(0, chunkLength).join(","));
    }
    return(result);
}
```

Comment: How would I incoprerate that in the function? I want it to return arrays of comma seperated strings based on the array.

Comment: My second block of code creates an array of comma separated strings.    The first block of code creates an array of arrays (where each inner array is no longer than a chunkSize).  What do those not do that you need?

Comment: I added sample output for each function so you can see what they each return.

Comment: I've created the same output, but made it much simpler using `splice`